# C# Convert DataView to Table (DataTable) in .NET 1.1

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, .net-1.1, rowfilter

I have a dataview on which I have set a rowfilter:

```
DataView dv = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;

dv.RowFilter = "here my filter";
```

Once data filtered, I want to convert it to a DataTable. I know this is possible in .NET 2.0 and above, using it:

```
Datatable result  = dv.ToTable();
```

But how to do this in .NET 1.1?

Comment: Out of curiosity Still, use .net 1.1..

Comment: Don't you already have a datatable : ds.Tables[0].  A dataset consists of datatables.

Comment: The source code of the framework is available. At first sight it doesn't seem to be impossible create a ToTable method yourself http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Data/a.html#8d3e2c3c04b09ed6

Comment: @too_cool Yes, it is a legacy project and it will be migrated soon in future. But now I need to do this modification.

Comment: Should have given a try but don't have VistualStudio to support that. :(

Comment: [Chk this out](http://www.codedigest.com/CodeDigest/54-Copy-the-Sorted-Filtered-Dataview-To-DataTable-in--Net-1-1.aspx) Might help

Comment: @Steve i get error on line List<object[]> rowlist = new List<object[]>(); when trying to adapt it. Net 1.1 does not recognize it.

Comment: @too_cool I'll try it. thx.

Answer (score 0):

How about this a workaround using Datatable  `Select`

```
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
DataTable filterdt = dt.Clone(); //Available from .Net 1.1

//Datatable Select Available from .Net 1.1              
DataRow[] filterRows = dt.Select("here you filter"); 



 //Loop filterRows[] and import to filterdt Datatable

  foreach (DataRow filterRow in filterRows)
                filterdt.ImportRow(filterRow); //Datatable Import row Available from .Net 1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in .NET 1.1 because the enumerator of the `DataView` only returns the filtered rows:

```
DataTable table = dv.Table.Clone();
foreach (DataRowView rowView in dv)
    table.ImportRow(rowView.Row);
```